# How to resolve caching issues in dynamics 365 portals?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, adxstudio-portals

I am very new to portals.I am facing caching issues in portal. After clearing cache only i can see my data updated.Please suggest me a link which i can refer for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to setup for [Web Notification](https://community.adxstudio.com/products/adxstudio-portals/documentation/developers-guide/cache/web-notifications/) for cache invalidation.

> An Adxstudio Portal application caches results from CRM to improve
>   performance. In order for the portal to get fresh data from CRM, we
>   have to configure the cache invalidation in CRM to notify the portal
>   of CRM data changes. This is done by adding a Web Notification URL in
>   CRM. A Web Notification Plugin registered with the Adxstudio Portals
>   solution in CRM is triggered on all entity create, update, delete,
>   disassociate, associate, publish, and publishall messages and notifies
>   the Web Notification URLs defined in the CRM to invalidate the cache
>   so the users visiting the portal get the recent data changes.

Comment: I am not looking for notifications and i have got my answer from the above comment, i think that was deleted but that actually answers my question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1kNYDyZ3fE&t=55s

Comment: @CodingFreak so is your question about MIcrosoft Portals or Adxstudio Portals?

Comment: Microsoft portals and that is the reason that links helped me. Thanks :)